# Have ctrl+c interrupt a blocking system call

Tags: windows, blocking, thread-sleep, interrupt-handling, keyboardinterrupt

Here is a slimmed down example of the code I'm working with:

```
void SleepIntr()
{
    printf("Entering sleep...\n");
    SleepEx(10000, TRUE);
    printf("Sleep done...\n");
}
static BOOL WINAPI ctrl_handler(DWORD dwCtrlType) {
    printf("ctrl_handler pressed\n");
    // Wake program up!
    return TRUE;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrl_handler, TRUE);
    SleepIntr();
    printf("awake!\n"); 
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is that when ctr+c is pressed, the sleep should be interrupted and the program should continue executing and print "awake!" Or at least give me a stack trace of where the execution was when ctrl+c was pressed.

The `SleepEx` call could be any system call that blocks, such a blocking read from a socket.

*What should I write in my `ctrl_handler` to have the call interrupted?* Short of terminating the whole process I've found nothing. If it is impossible then I'll accept that as an answer but I really want to know why.

Here is the equivalent program coded for Linux, using `nanosleep` instead of `SleepEx`:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
void ctrl_c (int sid, siginfo_t *info, void *data) {
    printf("Im a ctrl_c\n");
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sigaction act = {0};
    act.sa_sigaction = &ctrl_c;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);
    struct timespec t, t2;
    t.tv_sec = 5;
    t.tv_nsec = 0;
    printf("sleep start\n");
    nanosleep (&t, &t2);
    printf("sleep end\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It works exactly like I want it. Ctrl+c in nanosleep immediately interrupts it and execution continues by printing "sleep end". Why can't something similar work for SleepEx on Windows?

**EDIT** Second argument to `SleepEx` should of course be TRUE. That was a typo.

Comment: That is not an option.  You've got 5 seconds to do something with the callback.  If you don't terminate the program before that then Windows will do it for you.  You are free to ignore a close request in a gui program as long as you like.  Writing code that's safely abortable is a programmer's job, that starts by not sleeping a thread for 10 seconds of course.  You unblock a I/O call by closing the handle.

Comment: `nanosleep` is specifically documented to exit when a signal is received, similar to the way `SleepEx` will exit when an APC is queued, *provided* you set `bAlertable` to `TRUE`.  The only difference is that in Windows the programmer can choose whether or not the sleep is interruptible. Of course, in Linux the programmer could always call `nanosleep` in a loop, checking whether or not the time has elapsed.  That's equivalent to setting `bAlertable` to `FALSE`, just less convenient: and it would stop you from interrupting the code just as effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no getting around the fact that you need to know what you're interrupting, and that the code has to be designed to be interrupted.

In the particular example you've chosen, replace the sleep with a timed wait on an event.  You can then interrupt it by setting the event.

If you're making a synchronous I/O call, you can use `CancelSynchronousIo` but of course the code handling the I/O then has to properly handle the cancellation.

If you're in an alertable wait you can queue an APC to the thread.

If you're in a message loop you can post a message or have the loop use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`.

***Additional:*** demo code showing demonstrating how to wake `SleepEx`

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

HANDLE mainthread;

VOID CALLBACK DummyAPCProc(
  _In_  ULONG_PTR dwParam
)
{
    printf("User APC\n");
    return;
}

void SleepIntr()
{
    printf("Entering sleep...\n");
    SleepEx(10000, TRUE);
    printf("Sleep done...\n");
}

static BOOL WINAPI ctrl_handler(DWORD dwCtrlType) {
    printf("ctrl_handler pressed\n");
    // Wake program up!
    if (!QueueUserAPC(DummyAPCProc, mainthread, NULL))
    {
        printf("QueueUserAPC: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return TRUE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (!DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentThread(), GetCurrentProcess(), &mainthread, GENERIC_ALL, FALSE, 0))
    {
        printf("DuplicateHandle: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrl_handler, TRUE);
    SleepIntr();
    printf("awake!\n"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm writing a vm which is supposed to be able to handle misbehaving code nicely (without hanging), so replacing SleepEx with a better function isn't always an option. I take it some combination of `CancelSynchronousIO` and `QueueUserAPC` is the best I can do?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.  What if the misbehaving code is `for (;;);` ?

Comment: Then I'm out of luck of course. However that kind of misbehaving isn't as common as being stuck in a blocking read on a socket or similar. That's the kind of things I want to be able to interrupt.

Comment: Well, `CancelSynchronousIo` will do it - if you know which thread to target - but odds are that the code won't know how to respond to the I/O being terminated, and will wind up either crashing, exiting the process with an error message, or in a generally nonfunctional state.  As for alertable waits, they should always be called in a loop, so there's probably not much you can do.

Comment: That's ok. The blocking function is called using a kind of byte code, so as long as the function returns the vm can regain control and proceed cleanly. Hard to explain clearly, but what calls `SleepEx` and friends isn't C code at all but Factor. However, I've experimented now a lot with `CancelSynchronousIO` and `QueueUserAPC` and none of them actually breaks the `SleepEx` call. At least not the one in my example.

Comment: No, because you've set bAlertable to FALSE, so the sleep is uninterruptible.  If you can force bAlertable to be TRUE, an APC will work.  Or, if you know for a fact that the thread in question is calling `SleepEx` I guess you could terminate just that particular thread.

Comment: That was a typo. But even with TRUE it still wont work. At least not if `SleepEx` is called from the main thread.

Comment: Can you post the code?  Queuing an APC should cause an alertable sleep to wake.

Comment: I'm just inserting a call to `QueueUserAPC(&noop, thread, 0)` (where thread is the handle of the main thread) where I've written `// Wake program up!`.

Comment: Thanks!! It was the DuplicateHandle() call I was missing. Now it works exactly as inteded for QueueUserAPC() calls so it should be trivial to add the same ctrl+c aborting for CancelSynchronousIO() too.